Upgraded to 24.04 and no GUI desktop
I let the system upgrade proceed and after reboot it drops to the shell. When I run startx to start the desktop, it freezes the system and removes keyboard access.
What causes this? My computer and monitor are only 3 years old, and the previous version, 20.

It is difficult to diagnose with that much information. In my experience, when I faced such issue I could boot in safe mode to repair my installation. The repair involved fixing some of the apt repositories I had to official ones and removing AMD ROCm packages

Thank you for the information. You are correct, I had some install failures, that I had missed, and had to repair that and install the desktop again. All is working correctly now.
